# How can I find the matching features from two images when the matrices containing their extracted features are of different size?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction, matlab-cvst, sift

```
img1 = imread('01.01.bmp');
img2 = imread('01.02.bmp');

feature1 = sift_f(img1);
feature2 = sift_f(img2);


indexPairs = matchFeatures(feature1,feature2) ;
matchedPoints1 = vpts1(indexPairs(:,1));
matchedPoints2 = vpts2(indexPairs(:,2));
figure; showMatchedFeatures(img1,img2,matchedPoints1,matchedPoints2);
legend('matched points 1','matched points 2');
```

The matrices feature1 and feature2 are of different sizes. Infact, they differ in the number of columns. So, matchFeatures() function is not working. How do I match the features then?

Comment: This is of course highly dependent of the inputs. Try to resize the inital images to the same resolution and after that it should work

Comment: What is the size of the matrices?

Answer (score 0):

`matchFeatures` expects `features1` and `features2` to be matrices, where each row is a feature vector. So it expects `features1` and `features2` to have the same number of columns, but the number of rows can be different. It may be that you simply need to transpose `features1` and `features2` before passing them into `matchFeatures`.

What are the sizes of `features1` and `features2`? The length of a SIFT descriptor is typically 128. So if the sizes are 128-by-N, then you definitely need to transpose them.